# Redirecionar domínio .com.br para .com

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirecionamento

Possuo dois domínios: o principal é o .com e o secundário é o .com.br

Preciso fazer com que toda vez que acessem www.dominio.com.br ele redirecione para o www.dominio.com, até mesmo quando possui uma subpasta, por exemplo: www.dominio.com.br/teste redirecione para www.dominio.com/teste

O host que utilizo é o iPage.

Comment: Em qual linguagem está seu site?

Comment: Isso influencia em algo? É só uma página em HTML com um formulário, utilizando PHP para o envio do mesmo.

Comment: Influencia na minha resposta. Recentemente tive um problema como isso em uma plataforma que desenvolvi a base de C# e tenho um código pronto que faz as verificações e direcionamentos. Portanto infelizmente não consigo ajudar

Comment: Tudo bem amigo! Obrigado de qualquer forma!

Comment: Está usando servidor apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possui .htaccess? Servidor apache? 
Você poderia usar mod_rewrite para fazer isso.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Era isso mesmo!

Comment: Ok! Não esqueça de colocar as TAG que faltam para as suas perguntas. Abraço.

Comment: Só para completar a resposta, aqui tem um tutorialzinho do iPage
https://www.ipage.com/support/tutorials/view_tutorial.bml?kbid=6104 Logo no começo ele mostra a tela onde editar o htaccess, e outras formas de redirecionar o teu domínio.